# DMI table unreliable?

Tags: linux, administration, dmidecode, smbios

From the `dmidecode` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) :

> the presented information [is] possibly unreliable.

They also add:

> More often than not, information contained in the DMI tables is inaccurate, incomplete or simply wrong.

[Here is an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306759/dmidecode-differs-from-lspci#306778)  where the DMI table data differs from using other PCI utilities. Under what circumstances is data in the DMI table inaccurate?

Comment: Typically motherboard manufacturers do not complete the customization of the BIOS which they outsource. For example on my motherboard I see `Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.`

Comment: The DMI table is just data in the BIOS. If whoever put together your BIOS put wrong data in, or if someone flashed a new BIOS with wrong tables, then the tables won't describe reality. But there's no easy way to *detect* this.

Comment: That makes sense thanks. Seems strange something like the physical addresses of system slots could be wrong without things breaking... I guess not much depends on DMI